What if someone married their Paternal Cousin?
We all know Arjun and Subhadra were cousins yet they got married, even Lord Krishna was present and let it happen so we can understand it as acceptable.
I've come around many answers saying that you cannot marry a same gotra cousin, in Buddha's case he also married his first cousin but they did not have same gotra because he married maternal cousin sister.
It seems that you can marry your Maternal uncle/aunt's children.
But not your Paternal uncle/aunt's children.
My question is what if someone married their Paternal cousin? (Assume first Cousin for the case)
What will be their punishment? Will they burn in hell for this sin?

Cross cousins are allowed to marry. Parallel cousins arent, atleast this is the norm where I am from. Also this is allowed for people from south of Vindyas in some smruthi
